Minimizing the trace of matrix using matrix calculus
If I have a function $f(X)$ that returns a square matrix, and $f(X)$ is a convex function with respect to matrix $X$, I sometimes see literature just tell me $\partial f(X)/ \partial X = 0$ will minimize the trace of $f(X)$
For example Kalman Gain Derivation says "the trace is minimized when its matrix derivative with respect to the gain matrix is zero"
Basically from this expression:
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k} & = \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} - \mathbf{K}_k \mathbf{H}_k \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} - \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} \mathbf{H}_k^\textsf{T} \mathbf{K}_k^\textsf{T} + \mathbf{K}_k \left(\mathbf{H}_k \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} \mathbf{H}_k^\textsf{T} + \mathbf{R}_k\right) \mathbf{K}_k^\textsf{T} \\[6pt]
                       &= \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} - \mathbf{K}_k \mathbf{H}_k \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} - \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} \mathbf{H}_k^\textsf{T} \mathbf{K}_k^\textsf{T} + \mathbf{K}_k \mathbf{S}_k\mathbf{K}_k^\textsf{T}
\end{align}
to minimize the trace, Wikipedia went on to compute
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \; \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{P}_{k\mid k})}{\partial \;\mathbf{K}_k} = 0\end{align}

Are there a rigorous proof and an intuitive explanation of why that is the case?

What is X here?

@lisyarus X is a matrix

I know nothing about optimization, but this probably has something to do with the fact the trace usually shows up in formulas for matrix derivatives, for example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula. maybe go through the proof of that and see if anything applies to your situation

What do you mean by $P_{k|l}$ ?

@JeanMarie I'm just citing an example from wikipedia about kalman filter.  my main question is why $\partial f(X)/ \partial X = 0$  minimizes the trace of $f(X)$

Are you asking why the minimum of a (multivariate) function $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is the solution of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=0$ for $i=1,\dots,n$?!?

@TedBlack apologies if this is a basic question but I failed to see how that's related to matrix calculus.

$\frac{\partial ; \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{P}_{k\mid k})}{\partial ;\mathbf{K}_k} $ generates the partial derivatives of a multivariate function whose variables are the elements of $\mathbf{K}_k$. Matrix calculus allows you to do this efficiently.

$\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}$
$\def\qty#1{\left(#1\right)}$
To understand this think of the following simple problem. You are given a matrix,
$$
\mathbf{X}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y \\
z &  t
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and two other matrices,
\begin{align}
{\bf  A }& = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c &  d
\end{bmatrix} \\
{\bf B }& = \begin{bmatrix}
e & f \\
g &  h
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
You are asked to find values for $x,y,z,t$ for which,
$$
\phi=\tr \qty{\mathbf{X}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{X}^\top-\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}}
$$
is minimized. There are two ways of solving this.
The first is to recognize that $\phi$ is a multivariate (scalar) function of $x,y,z,t$. Since,
$$
\mathbf{X}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{X}^\top - \mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}=
\left[\begin{matrix}- a x - b z + x \left(e x + g y\right) + y \left(f x + h y\right) & - a y - b t + t \left(f x + h y\right) + z \left(e x + g y\right)\\- c x - d z + x \left(e z + g t\right) + y \left(f z + h t\right) & - c y - d t + t \left(f z + h t\right) + z \left(e z + g t\right)\end{matrix}\right]
$$
we have,
$$
\phi(x,y,z,t)=
 t \left(f z + h t\right) + x \left(e x + g y\right) + y \left(f x + h y\right) + z \left(e z + g t\right) - a x - b z - c y - d t 
$$
To minimize $\phi$ calculate the following partial derivatives:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}
& = 2 e x + (f+g) y -a  \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}
& = (f +g) x + 2 h y - c\\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}
&=2 e z + (f +g) t -b\\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}
&= (f + g) z + 2 h t -d
\end{align}
The minimum of $\phi$ is obtained where $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=0$,
$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}=0$, $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}=0$, $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=0$ if the Hessian,
$$
{\bf H}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x\partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x\partial z} & \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x\partial t} \\
\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2} & \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y\partial z} & \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y\partial t} \\
\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z^2} & \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z\partial t} \\
\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t\partial z} & \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is positive definite. First lets evaluate the four conditions for the minimum:
\begin{align}
2e x + (f+g) y& = a \\
 (f +g) x + 2 h y& = c \\
 2 e z + (f +g) t &= b \\
 (f + g) z + 2 h t & =d
\end{align}
These can be consolidated in the following matrix equation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2e & f+g \\
f+g &  2h
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x & z \\
y &  t
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c &  d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We can recognize that,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2e & f+g \\
f+g &  2h
\end{bmatrix}
= {\bf B}+{\bf B}^\top
$$
and,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x & z \\
y &  t
\end{bmatrix}= {\bf X}^\top
$$
and so the optimal solution is given by,
$$
\qty{{\bf B}+{\bf B}^\top} {\bf X}^\top = {\bf A}
\implies {\bf X} = {\bf A}^\top \qty{{\bf B}+{\bf B}^\top}^{-1}
$$
The more efficient way is to use matrix calculus. Instead of calculating a multitude of partial derivatives summarise the optimal condition by writing,
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial {\bf X}}=0
$$
Then note that,
$$
\tr ({\bf A}{\bf X}) = \sum_{j} A_{ij}X_{ji} \implies
\frac{\partial \tr ({\bf A}{\bf X})}{\partial {X_{pq}}}=\sum_{j} A_{ij}\delta_{jp}\delta_{iq}=A_{qp}
$$
and,
$$
\tr ({\bf X}{\bf B}{\bf X}^\top)=\sum_{j}\sum_{k} X_{ij}B_{jk}X_{ik} \implies
\frac{\partial \tr ({\bf X}{\bf B}{\bf X}^\top)}{\partial {X_{pq}}}=
\sum_{j}\sum_{k} \qty{\delta_{ip}\delta_{qj}B_{jk}X_{ik}+X_{ij}B_{jk}\delta_{ip} \delta_{kq} } = \sum_k B_{qk}X_{pk} + \sum_j X_{pj}B_{jq}
$$
The first sum is equal to ${\bf B}{\bf X}^\top$ and the second sum is,
$$
\sum_j X_{pj}B_{jq} = \sum_j (B^\top)_{qj} (X^\top)_{jp}= {\bf B}^\top {\bf X}^\top
$$
and so we obtain,
$$
\qty{{\bf B}+{\bf B}^\top}{\bf X}^\top - {\bf A}=0
$$
which is the same condition we derived using multivariate calculus. Note that now it is much easier to determine whether this solution is a minimum. Since,
$$
\frac{\partial \qty{{\bf B}+{\bf B}^\top}{\bf X}^\top - {\bf A}}{\partial {\bf X}} = {\bf B}+{\bf B}^\top
$$
then if ${\bf B}+{\bf B}^\top$ has positive eigenvalues the condition is satisfied. Note that,
$$
{\bf H}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2e & f+g & 0 & 0 \\
f+g & 2h & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2e & f+ g \\
0 & 0 & f+g & 2h
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
{\bf B}+{\bf B}^\top & {\bf O}\\
{\bf O} & {\bf B}+{\bf B}^\top
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and so $\bf H$ is positive definite iff ${\bf B}+{\bf B}^\top$ is positive definite.

$
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\green#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\blue#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=0}^\infty}
\def\Sj{\sum_{j=\o}^k}
$Here's a sketch of the idea.
Consider the Taylor expansion of a scalar function
and its first derivative
$$\eqalign{
f(z) = \Sk \a_k\,z^k, \qq
f'(z) = \Sk k\a_k\,z^{k-1} \\
}$$
Apply the function to a matrix argument and take its trace
$$\eqalign{
\phi
 &= \trace{f(X)} \;=\; I:\Sk\a_kX^k \\
}$$
Calculate the differential and gradient of $\phi$
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
 &= I:\Sk\a_k\BR{\Sj X^{k-j}\,dX\;X^{j-\o}} \\
 &= \Sk\a_k\BR{\Sj X^{k-j}\,I\;X^{j-\o}}^T : dX \\
 &= \BR{\Sk\a_k\LR{kX^{k-\o}}}^T : dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X} &= \BR{\Sk k\a_k\,X^{k-\o}}^T \;\equiv\; f'\!\LR{X^T} \\
}$$
The zero gradient condition yields the desired result.

$^{**}$In the preceding, a colon denotes the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
}$$
which has the following algebraic properties
$$\eqalign{
B:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{PQ}:B &= P:\LR{BQ^T} \;=\; Q:\LR{P^TB} \\
}$$
